# .mouseover(function( ) not working working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have 2 carousels, one that initiates on mouse click on the controls and another that initiates the slides on mouseover.

This works perfectly in all browsers except IE 10.

Is there any workaround?

Here's the code for the problematic carousel:

```
$(function() {
$(window).load(function() {

$('#myCarousel1').carousel('pause');
});


$('#myCarousel1').carousel({interval:false});
var myInterval=false;
$('.side-slide').mouseover(function() {
var ctrl = $(this);
var interval=400;

myInterval = setInterval(function(){
     ctrl.trigger("click");
},interval);
});

$('.carousel-control').mouseout(function(){
clearInterval(myInterval);
myInterval = false;
});
});
```

Thank you

Comment: 1. What Internet Explorer version did you check? 2. Please upload your problem to http://www.jdfiddle.net

Comment: Did you check the IE10 console for any errors? Press F12 to see console and check for any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try jQuery's `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Comment: Hi Artek, please help me with the markup structure. I'm fluent in HTML and CSS, not so much jQuery

Comment: Just try replacing `mouseover` with `mouseenter` and `mouseout` with `mouseleave` and post your results.

Comment: please post full example on jsfiddle, and we'll check it